# Virtual methods and inhertitance design

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, virtual, object-oriented-analysis

Consider we have abstract `base class A` with virtual method `foo1()` that is calling some other virtual method `foo2()`.(foo1 and foo2 implemented in base class level but also virtual)

I've also `class B` which is concrete class that inherits from `class A`.
Now, `Class A` had inherited `foo1()` (and of course `foo2()`, but if I want to do the same operation of `foo1()` but this time by calling `foo3()` instead of `foo2()`, how can I do that and what is the best practice/design to do so?

I see some options, guess there are better ones

1. Override foo1() in `class B` and write same code as in `base.foo1()` but change calling of `foo2()` to `foo3()` --> this is some what code duplication because all code is similar except calling to `foo2()` or `foo3()`.
2. Overriding `foo2()` in concrete class B.
   Is that mean that now inherited `foo1()` will lunch `foo2()` overridden version of `class B` or it will still take implementation of same level `class A`?

This is the code sample for option 2:(more like pseudo code)

```
public abstract Class A
{
    public virtual void foo1()
    {
        doing some actions123
        foo2();
        doing some actions4
    }

    public virtual void foo2()
    {
        Console.writeln("Class A foo2");
    }
}

public Class B : A
{
    public override void foo2()
    {
        foo3();
    }

    public void foo3()
    {
        Console.writeln("Class B foo3");
    }
}

public static void main()
{ 
    B bClass = new B();
    B.foo1();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Always most overridden implementation gets called. So option 2 will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 2 is the way to go. Override foo2 in class B and whenever foo1 in class A gets called it will then call foo2 in class B.